# Syntax Query, calling modules in Visual C++

Tags: c++

I have tried to adapt my knowledge of modularity to Visual C++ however, upon what seems to be an endless search scouring for syntax, I simply can't get this right. Basically in this code, the menu is called first, once the user enters their choice (only coded option 1 thus far) to return that value to the main, which then steps into the if statement and calls fahrenheit. I am requesting the syntax for passing by reference, I know C#'s syntax for this, but not Visual C++

Here's the code.

```
    // Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void Celsius()
{
}

void fahrenheit()
{
    cout << "Success!" << endl; //....Outputs this just to see if the module is being called properly.
}

int menu(int Mystring) //....I was testing this syntax to pass the variable.
{
    cout << "What would you like to do : " << endl;
    cout << "1) Fanreheit to Celsius" << endl;
    cout << "2) Celsius to Fahrenheit" << endl;

    cout << "Choice : " ;

    cin >> Mystring;

    return Mystring;
}

int main()
{
    int celsius = 0;
    int fahrenheit = 0;
    int Mystring = 0;

    menu(Mystring); //....Testing this syntax to pass Mystring to menu.

    if (Mystring == 1) //....I was hoping the menu would return Mystring as value = 1.
    {
        fahrenheit(); //.......I want this to call fahrenheit module if Mystring = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse the grammatical mistakes please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "things" you're talking about aren't called *modules*, but *functions*. That's a pretty big difference and I think you *should* know it, since you won't understand nearly any article without that knowledge.

That being cleared, the problem in your code is, that you pass the variable by **value** (`int menu(int Mystring)`), while - in order to change it inside the function - you need to pass it by **reference** or **pointer**:

```
int menu(int &Mystring)
```

There are plenty of [articles](http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++/argsC++.html) about functions in C++. You should check them out probably.

Comment: I will try that syntax, is there any code I need to add the the calling code menu(Mystring)? my tutor calls functions modules in C# I do know the difference between the two, (by value and by reference) yes and use the ref syntax in C#

Comment: also, to expand, I have fahrenheit(Mystring) I have just added, in which Visual C++ asks for a pointer-to- function type.

Comment: Your declaration of function `fahrenheit` doesn't take any parameters. If you want to pass variables to the function, change the declaration. Also - please actually **read** the article I linked in my post, it answers all your questions so far.

Comment: I'm reading it as we speak, I apologize for any inconvenience.